# What does the -R flag do for chflags?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix, man

I'm not clear on exactly what the `-R` flag does for `chflags`. I was wondering if someone might be able to help me.

The man page says this:

> Recurse: Change the file flags of file hierarchies rooted in the files
> instead of just the files themselves.

I don't understand what that means. Can someone tell me what the difference would be between `chflags -R hidden` and just `chflags hidden`?

There's an online man page here for reference: http://ss64.com/mac/chflags.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursive flag is used for directories to apply same thing to the every included file and directory(recursively again). You could also run your command without -R option for directories but it will only affect the directory itself.

If you have a directory structure as follows:

```
mainDir  
|_file1  
|_file2  
|_dir1  
 |_dir1_file1
 |_dir1_file2
```

You should run chflags with -R option to change all files flags including the lower level files(dir1_file1).